# [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostbyAddress COMPARE strings

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file with hostnames and their IP addresses and I've to deploy something on them but, I can only use their IP addresses.

So I need to confirm if the IP address stills matching the hostname before start the deployment.

I wrote this script but is not doing what I expected...
Anyone can see where is the problem?

Thanks

```
$computerName = 'testName'
$computerIP = '192.168.32.148'

$var1 = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostbyAddress("$computerIP").hostname

if ($var1 -like $computerName) {

    "$computerName IS LIKE $var1"
}else{
    "$computerName NOT LIKE $var1"
}
```

OUTPUT

```
testName NOT LIKE testName.mycompany.net
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
testName IS LIKE testName.mycompany.net
```

Comment: Hi, your code seems to work on my own computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-like` uses exact wildcard matching, and you're not using any wildcards in your `-like` operation!

Try this:

```
if ($var1 -like "$computerName*") {
    "$computerName IS LIKE $var1"
}else{
    "$computerName NOT LIKE $var1"
}
```

(Notice the `*` after the `$computerName` value)

For more information about wildcard matching, check out [`Get-Help about_Wildcards`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847812.aspx)